# ImportError _pywrapsat module Google OR-Tools for Python

Tags: python, module, importerror, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm looking into developing an employee scheduling program for the department I work with.
Various examples of such programs already exist and are shared online, one of these is the following: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py   (developed by Google).
As a first step I would like to tweak this code and run it, to see how far it gets me.

However when I try to run the exact GitHub code in PyCharm, the following error message pops-up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/---/PycharmProjects/---/scheduling.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ortools\sat\python\cp_model.py", line 59, in <module>
    from ortools.sat import pywrapsat
  File "C:\Users\---\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\ortools\sat\pywrapsat.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _pywrapsat

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrapsat: The specified module could not be found.
```

To overcome this problem, I completely deinstalled and reinstalled Python, Pycharm and the OR-Tools package. I even tried working my way around the problem by using Jupyter notebook, but the problem persists.

Does anyone know how I can import _pywrapsat so I can run the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encountering DLL error in OR Tools pywrapcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992381/encountering-dll-error-in-or-tools-pywrapcp)

Comment: Update: after reinstalling the visual studio 2019 redistributables, as suggested in the post @Stradivari linked to, the error is fixed. I can now run the code