# ortools DLL load failed using PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, dll, pyinstaller, or-tools

I used PyInstaller to create an executable GUI. It works perfectly fine on my own system (Windows), but if I run it on another Windows system I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainPlanner.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\tidi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "optimizer.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\tidi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "ortools\constraint_solver\pywrapcp.py", line 13, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
[141656] Failed to execute script mainPlanner
```

I have tried several ways of adding the DLL but I'm not familiar with this subject and not sure how to continue.

I create my executable through the spec file, which looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None

a = Analysis([my_path],
             pathex=[my_path_2],
             binaries = [],
             datas=[('data', 'data')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='mainPlanner',
          debug='all',
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , 
          icon='icon_path')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='mainPlanner')
```

I know I have to add something to the binaries variable, but haven't found the right dll yet. 
I have tried to find the ortools dll through the 'collect_dynamic_libs function from PyInstaller, but this returns an empty list.

Any help would be fantastic, really don't know what else to try.

Comment: It may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59992381/encountering-dll-error-in-or-tools-pywrapcp, does the other windows have the visual studio 2019 redistributables?

Comment: @Stradivari Yeah i saw that thread. I downloaded vs 2019 redistributables on the system that I use to create the app, but I honestly don't really see what the difference should be?  I ran the spec file from vs after i downloaded it, but nothing changed.

The other system doesn't have vs. I use it to test whether the executable can run independently of python or any other modules.

Comment: python ortools is a native library pakage i.e. a wrapper on a C++ library which depends on VS redistributable so you'll need it to run ortools python package on windows...